# XmlMassUpdate - How to delete a node

Tags: msbuild, web-config, xmlmassupdate

We would like to use msbuild to clear the connectionStrings section from a web.config file.

What is the easiest way to do that?

We have previously used XmlMassUpdate to replace values (see also this question: [XmlMassUpdate - Replace Value Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294438/xmlmassupdate-replace-value-node)), but have not found a way to remove it entirely.

More details:

We would like to change the section in web.config from

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Db1;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

to

```
<connectionStrings>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this in your substitutions file

```
<connectionStrings xmu:action="remove" />
```

This should completeley remove the `<connectionStrings>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add xmu:key="name" key="connectionString1" xmu:action="remove" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried something similar to the following and it seemed to work:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add xmu:key="name" name="connectionString1" xmu:action="remove" />
</connectionStrings>
```

(note `name=` instead of `key=`)

Comment: Note, there is a difference between this answer and Tom's (look carefully)